# Assigning variable or array to object element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got something like this which works, but I want to use the `result2` array for the first series`.data` rather than hardcoding. Using `data: result2` or `data: [result2]` does not work. Is it not possible to assign with a variable in this kind of declaration?

```
var chart1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get('sales_data', function(result) {
      var result2 = result.split(',');
      chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
         series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Units',
            data: [1, 3, 4]
         }, {
            type: 'line',
            name: '3 month avg',
            data: [2, 3, 4]
         }]
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: What's not working here?  `split` returns an array, not an object, just FYI.

Comment: it should just work `data: result2`. Have you tried it? If it's not working, check if `sales_data` is returning the correct string.

Comment: you didnt do anything with result2..?

Comment: This object feeds into a charting plugin. If I replace data: [1,3,4] with either data: [result2] or data: result2, the chart does not appear - it is blank. I used an alert(result2) to confirm that it has the data I need.

Comment: IN other words, this does not duplicate what I posted above:var chart1;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get('sales_data', function(result) {
      var result2 = result.split(',');
      chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
         series: [{
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Units',
            data: result2
         }, {
            type: 'line',
            name: '3 month avg',
            data: [2, 3, 4]
         }]
      });
   });
});

Comment: Am I confusing objects and arrays? Does result2 need to be an object to dupicate the data: [1,3,4] syntax?

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be the fact that if you're splitting a string, `result2` will be an array of strings.

I've never used `Highcharts`, but try parsing each element of the string into a corresponding array of integers, and then pass that array.

```
var strings = result.split(',');
var d = [];
for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
   d.push(parseInt(strings[i], 10));
```

Then, use `data: d` in your call to `Chart`.

Comment: I saw another example in Highcharts that used parseFloat and that has solved my problem - thank you both,

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that it is possible to do something like in JavaScript:

```
var arr = str.split(',');
var obj = {data: arr};
```

But, I think the problem might be that you're passing an array of strings to your charts API.

In your hard-coded example, you're passing in an array of integers. But if you call `split`, you'll get an array of strings. This could be the source of the problem.

So, try converting your string array into an array of numbers using parseInt or parseFloat before you pass it to the chart API.